# Get Package and their respective dependencies separately from 'yum update'

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, yum

If I type `yum update`, I can get all the missing packages and their dependencies for the system.

My question here is, is there a way to segregate all packages and their dependencies separately while running this command or is there another way to do the same?

[image: This is the output of <code>yum update</code>. This returns whole list of missing packages in the system]

[image: When I do <code>yum install PackageName</code> (here NetworkManager) I get all packages required to install that particular package.]

can we do this type of segregation(as in 2nd picture) in `yum update` for all packages rather than running the `yum install` cammad seperately? Is there any other way?

Comment: Just so I understand: what you want is the list of packages that don't have pre-requisites from that set, i.e. the shortest list of package names for `yum update p1 p2 p3...` that will directly or by dependency, update everything that's outdated?

Comment: if i run the command `yum install p1`, i get the list of missing dependencies for that package. When doing `yum update`, I get the whole list of missing packages(which include the `packages and its dependency packages`.). By any way can we get the whole list of missing packages by running a command, where package and its dependency packages are segregated respectively?

Comment: @Arun Can you take a sample output from `yum update` and show us how you want it to be displayed?

Comment: @Haxiel I have attached screenshots for better understanding

Comment: So effectively, you want to run `yum install _package_` (and then abort with no action) separately for every package that needs updating?

Comment: No. I know i can get the dependency list for individual packages separately with `yum install`. I wanted to know is there a way to get the whole list of missing packages along with their dependencies using any command.